# Obtaining the id of the row being edited from a GridView

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

My end goal is for my program to work like this:

- Press Edit button on GridView
- RowEditing event triggers, creating a new window
- New window with a DetailsView displays the full information.

I got all that to work, however, the DetailsView only displays the content from the *first entry* in the database table, instead of the entry which I pressed the edit button on.

So my question is, how can I tell the program which row is being edited on the GridView, and get the information(like the key) to make a new select statement on the DetailsView?

**TablePage.aspx**(with only the relevant code)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowEditing="RowEditing"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**TablePage.aspx.vb**(again, only relevant code)

```
Protected Sub RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    Dim url As String = "/tables/edit.aspx"
    Dim s As String = "window.open('" & url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=300s,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "script", s, True)
End Sub
```

Comment: it's always better to post any of your code to get solutions faster, can you at least post the gridview markup and the rowEditing event?

Comment: Updated my post with the relevant code, hopefully enough for your needs.

Comment: yes now I get it, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **e.NewEditIndex** from RowEditing function to get the current row edited in GridView, obtaining that you can access the row and get any cell text from the row.

Please try this:

```
Protected Sub RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
    'First, get the current RowIndex
    Dim selectedRowIndex As Integer = e.NewEditIndex

    'Then get any information you need from the row, for example the name of the first cell
    Dim selectedItemText As String = GridView1.Rows(selectedRowIndex).Cells(1).Text

    'Now you can store the information in session to use it in other page
    Session("EditParameter") = selectedItemText
    Dim url As String = "/tables/edit.aspx"

    Dim s As String = "window.open('" & url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=300s,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "script", s, True)
End Sub
```

Of course you can add another hidden bound field that contains the record number and then access it instead of the name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work at obtaining data from the edited row, thank you! Now I am figuring out how to use it to change the displayed data in the DetailsView.

Comment: glad it worked for you :) please mark this as an answer so that other people get benefit from it in the future.